# How to avoid reflect package to assess type of data?

Tags: go

For the below code:

```
type Tree struct {
    rootLabel interface{}
    branches  []Tree
}


func printTree(t Tree, nSpaces int) {
    labelValue := strings.Repeat("  ", nSpaces) + strconv.Itoa(label(t))
    fmt.Println(labelValue)
    for _, branch := range branches(t) {
        printTree(branch, nSpaces+1)
    }
}

func label(t Tree) interface{} {
    return t.rootLabel
}
```

---

`Tree` abstraction should allow any type of data to get stored in struct field `rootLabel`.

but in this syntax assuming `label()` returns `int`,

`labelValue := strings.Repeat("  ", nSpaces) + strconv.Itoa(label(t))`

`label(t)` returns `interface{}`

Type assertion & type switch needs guess work, so reflect package is the alternative.

But [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63527705/type-assertion-for-composite-types#comment112336327_63527705) is not to use `reflect` package.

`reflect.TypeOf(t).String()` may give `main.int` or `main.string`

---

For string labels createTree code looks like:

```
func createTree(label string, branches []Tree) Tree {

    for _, branch := range branches {
        assert(isTree(branch))
    }
    return Tree{
        rootLabel: label,
        branches: branches,
    }
}
```

---

```
$ go version
go version go1.14.3 linux/amd64
```

How to assess concrete type for the return value of `label(t)`?

Comment: I see the necessity of generics here. Do we have generics allowed in go 1.14?

Comment: Instead of `strconv.Itoa(label(t))` you could use `fmt.Sprint(label(t))` which uses reflection under the hood.

Comment: Type assertion requires no more "guess work" than reflection as far as figuring out the dynamic type of an interface value. For example if you have an interface value and you want to confirm that the dynamic type is an int, there is nothing simpler in Go than doing the following: `if _, ok := v.(int); ok { ... }`.

Comment: @Algebra8 That edit added extra indentation to all the code blocks.

Comment: @mkopriva `v.(int)` in type assertion or `v.(Type)` is guess work Isn't it?

Comment: @overexchange I didn't say there is "no guess work" I said there's "no **more** guess work *than* reflection". Which is more "guess work" (whatever that means) for you? `v.(int)` or `reflect.TypeOf(v).String() == "int"`.

Comment: @overexchange I was trying to point out the *unsoundness* of the claim you *seemed* to be making that, relfection is an alternative to *avoid* the "guess work" required when using type assertions. Also note that interfaces are the closest thing that will get you to something *like* generic code, if you want real generics you'll have to wait for Go2 or switch to a different language altogether.

Comment: @mkopriva can I instantiate a type after knowing the type from  `reflect.TypeOf(v).String()`?

Comment: @overexchange Do you need to?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg yes... for `createTree(label interface{}, branches []Tree)` constructor

Answer (score 0):

Well, as Zyl correctly wrote in the comments, there is an easier way to achieve that.

### Alternative 1: You get the trees from somewhere else

Basically, you can only move the "heavy" lifting, namely to `fmt.Printf`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

var foo = Tree{
    rootLabel: "rootLabel",
    branches: []Tree{
        Tree{
            rootLabel: 42,
            branches: []Tree{
                Tree{
                    rootLabel: "subbranch1",
                },
            },
        },
        Tree{
            rootLabel: "branch2",
            branches: []Tree{
                Tree{
                    rootLabel: []byte("frettled"),
                },
            },
        },
    },
}

type Tree struct {
    rootLabel interface{}
    branches  []Tree
}

func (t Tree) label() interface{} {
    return t.rootLabel
}

func (t *Tree) print(spaces int) {
    fmt.Printf("%s%v\n", strings.Repeat(" ", spaces*2), t.label())
    for _, b := range t.branches {
        b.print(spaces + 1)
    }
}

func main() {
    foo.print(0)
}
```

**<kbd>[Run on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/me4fiuZYpuP)</kbd>**
Basically, this does the trick.

### Alternative 2: You construct the trees

However, the above solution only moves the problem away from your code. Behind the scenes, reflection is used.

Let's think for a second. We want `rootLabel` to be able to be of any type. But we know one thing for sure: we want to print it. The empty `interface{}` too often is seen as a placeholder for "can be anything". Imho, it should be seen as "we know shit about it", sorry for the French. But we want to print `rootLabel` and since interfaces describe behavior, we need to find the appropriate interface. Here is where [fmt.Stringer](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) comes into play. So basically, all we need to do is to change the code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

// StringLabel is a label that implements fmt.Stringer
type StringLabel string

// String implements fmt.Stringer for StringLabel
func (l StringLabel) String() string {
    return string(l)
}

// ByteSliceLabel is a label that implements fmt.Stringer
type ByteSliceLabel []byte

// String implements fmt.Stringer for ByteSliceLabel
func (l ByteSliceLabel) String() string {
    return string(l)
}

// IntLabel is a label that implements fmt.Stringer
type IntLabel int

// String implements fmt.Stringer for IntLabel
func (l IntLabel) String() string {
    return strconv.Itoa(int(l))
}

// Bar is an arbitrary example struct.
// However, as long as it implements fmt.Stringer, you can use it as a label.
type Bar struct {
    Id  int
    Baz string
}

// String implements fmt.Stringer for Bar
func (b *Bar) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%03d-%s", b.Id, b.Baz)
}

var foo = Tree{
    rootLabel: StringLabel("rootLabel"),
    branches: []Tree{
        Tree{
            rootLabel: IntLabel(42),
            branches: []Tree{
                Tree{
                    rootLabel: ByteSliceLabel([]byte("frettled")),
                },
            },
        },
        Tree{
            rootLabel: StringLabel("branch2"),
            branches: []Tree{
                Tree{
                    rootLabel: StringLabel("subbranch2"),
                },
                Tree{
                    rootLabel: &Bar{Id: 1, Baz: "lorem"},
                },
            },
        },
    },
}

type Tree struct {
    rootLabel fmt.Stringer
    branches  []Tree
}

func (t Tree) label() interface{} {
    return t.rootLabel
}

func (t *Tree) print(spaces int) {
    fmt.Printf("%s%v\n", strings.Repeat(" ", spaces*2), t.label())
    for _, b := range t.branches {
        b.print(spaces + 1)
    }
}
func main() {
    foo.print(0)
}
```

**<kbd>[Run on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6fRCQWUpLA5)</kbd>**